# Ajax modal popup position on small screens

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax

I have the following modal popup on a Asp.net/C# web application. The modal popup holds multiple placeholders. My problem occurs when I am trying to access the modal popup on small screens or on ipad/iphone/ipod screens. The page display the half of the modal popup so the information in the top are inaccessible. I have used overflow:auto;/ the following solution: [Mobile ModalPopupExtender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237187/mobile-modalpopupextender)  and many others but doesn’t solved my problem.

> .modalBackground {
>       background-color:Gray;
>       filter:alpha(opacity=70);
>       opacity:0.7; } .modalPopup {
>       background-color:#ffffdd;
>       border-width:3px;
>       border-style:solid;
>       border-color:Gray;
>       padding:3px;
>       width:250px; }

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button  ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" style="display:none" /> 

              <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel1" RepositionMode="None" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlpopup" 
TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
    DropShadow="true"   
 BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">

        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" BackColor="LightGray" style="display:none;"
             CssClass="modalPopup" Width="650px" >
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
</ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                      <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Height="30px" Width="160px" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                     </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I recently came across this problem on your website, what i did is in javascript, i check the innerheight of page and depending on that, i add scroll bar on my modal popup.

Comment: Can you help me with the javascript? Sample code?

Comment: What is you desirable behavior? Move popup, make it adaptive(smaller)?

Comment: yes make it adaptive. Smaller

Comment: sorry for reviving the deads, but.. did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

@focus: As I am using Jquery to attach ModalPopup to a button but code I used to check innerheight and then add class to my panel is:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
if (height < 1000) {        
    $("#pnlpopup").addClass("PanelWithScroll");       
}
```

You need to add above code in javascript and this need to be called on `ModalPopupExtender` click.

`PanelWithScroll` is a css class:

```
.PanelWithScroll{
height:250px;
overflow:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Similarly, if you have problem with width too, you can check width too (http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/) and change class `PanelWithScroll`

Other thing you can do is check page height on page_load and if its less than what you want, add this class to `pnlpopup` Div. (This is easy solution IMO)

Update:

Add given javascript in your HTML Code in head section

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var height = window.innerHeight;
if (height < 1000) {        
    $("#pnlpopup").addClass("PanelWithScroll");       
   }
}
```

`$(document).ready` will only run after your page has wholly rendered. This may also help if you need help on how to put script in html (http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html)

Comment: The modal popup is called from the code behind this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show() how can i call the javascript also?